# how to run a script using cron which imports a user defined function from another location?

Tags: python, ubuntu, cron

I am new to `ubuntu`,`cron`.

I have set up a script which imports a function defined by me.

When I try to run the script from pycharms it works.

When executing through `cron` it throws an error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "/home//PycharmProjects/PMS/placeorder.py", line 2, in 
>      from allpurpose.webdrivercommands import sendkeys,clickelem_id
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'allpurpose'

`cron`

```
9 00 * * * /path/to/virtual/env /path/to/script
```

The import is from a file in the /home/PycharmProjects folder

Comment: Is ^/path/to/virtual/env` a wrapper script with a weird name, or a directory? The latter won't work. Make your other script into a module and install it in the virtual env; that's what they are for.

Comment: @tripleee it is a directory. I did exactly as you said last night as a trial and it worked. :) Please post it as an answer so I can accept it. Thanks

Comment: Lucky guess based on very incomplete information. I'm afraid I don't think this is likely to help future visitors; but if you don't want to delete this question, you are certainly welcome to answer it yourself.

Answer (score -1):

I am posting this just incase someone stumbles into a similar position:

The error above is because my virtual environment did not have the script I wanted to import. I resolved it by moving the script to:

```
/path/to/virtual/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/folder
```

the `/folder` is `allpurpose` in my case above.

Comment: the folder path should be passed as an argument to the cron script. And the final path should be constructed before import..